# need a search query for mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

If keyword is given as **red shirt**, the result set should be like

If I use this query `{$text: {$search: "\""+req.body.productName+"\""}}`
getting result as

> Shop this orange colou**red shirt** fabric and get noticed everywhere
>   this fabric comes from the house of Fashion Foreplus The leading men s
>   Fashion store Cotton blend and vibrant soft colour gives yo

but I need the result

> Shop this  **red** orange colour fabric and get noticed everywhere
>   this fabric comes from the house **shirt** of Faslike

If the given keyword is at of different places even though I should get a result.

Comment: i have tried this query db.collection('collection').find({$text: {$search: "\"red shirt\""}})

Comment: In which property you are storing `coloured red`? Can you post single document here

Comment: {
    "_id" : ObjectId("57d110a78137536c0a0ca258"),
    
    "ProductName" : "Fashion Foreplus Striped Cotton Blend ShirtFabric1431",
    "ProductDescription" : "Shop this orange coloured shirt fabric and get noticed everywhere  this fabric comes from the house of Fashion Foreplus  The leading men s Fashion store  Cotton blend and vibrant soft colour  gives yo"
 
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query

```
db.collection('collection').find({ProductName:new RegExp('red shirt', 'i')})
```

Comment: getting the same result

Comment: db.collection('collection').find({ProductName:new RegExp('red shirt', 'i')}) i should get the result which contains both the words red and shirt, but need not to be side by side, but both words should present

Comment: Try using the word boundary around red and shirt. `new RegExp('\bred\sshirt\b','i')`

Comment: You can use $or in your query `db.getCollection('tasks').find({$or:[{ProductName:new RegExp('shirt', 'i')},{ProductName:new RegExp('red', 'i')}]})`

Comment: And if your text has `red shirt` in one place then it will work with single query

Comment: If you put 'red shirt' in `regExp` the all the documents will come who contains this text in one place.

Comment: yes but i need to get red and shirt both to be present in the result set.

Comment: Can you put some objects and put your expected value in question? Since there are some misunderstanding

Comment: { "ProductName" : "Fashion Foreplus Striped Cotton Blend ShirtFabric1431", "ProductDescription" : "Shop this orange shirt fabric and get noticed everywhere this fabric comes from the house of Fashion Foreplus The leading men s Fashion store Cotton red blend and vibrant soft colour gives yo" }, { "ProductName" : "Fashion Foreplus Striped Cotton Blend ShirtFabric1431", "ProductDescription" : "Shop this orange shirt fabric and get noticed everywhere this fabric comes from the house of Fashion Foreplus The leading men s Fashion store Cotton blend and vibrant soft colour gives yo" }

Comment: above comment is the example document-----------search word as "red shirt"--- in above objects 1st contains red and shirt words and 2nd doesn't contain red--- so ineed to get 1st object as result as it contains both red and shirt.-------search should be done on both productname and productdescription

Comment: mean you also want to get filtered property which only matches that value?

Comment: yes i want to get document which contains the all words of search value.

Answer (score 0):

this wont work @kalyan Manthena. Reason :

check you product description :Shop this orange coloured shirt fabric and get noticed everywhere this fabric comes from the house of Fashion Foreplus The leading men s Fashion store Cotton blend and vibrant soft colour gives yo.

now imagine that the text index is built on Product Description field and you run a query for

db.yourCollection.find({$text:{$search:"red shirt"}})

will do stemming and try to match red and shirt in the description and though it didnot find red (as a word) it do finds shirt and gives back the whole description.

your excepted result: Shop this red orange colour fabric and get noticed everywhere this fabric comes from the house shirt of Faslike

does this text even exist for any of the product in your collection ? Mongo cannot build text for you. it can only query what lays in the system.